# Assigning a normal to stl vertex with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, stl

In an stl file, there are facet normals, then a list of verticies.  In some stl files I work with, there are multiples of the same vertex, for example, a file with 5 million verticies, is usually containing 30 duplicates of each vertex.  Such as, a cylinder cut out of a cube, has one vertex that belongs to 20 other triangles.

For this reason, I like to store the verticies in a hash table, that allows me to upload the index set of verticies for the triangle, reducing a mesh from 5 million verticies to 900k.

This however, creates a normal issue for the facet, which uses the first facet normal to assign to the first instance of the vertex.

What is the fastest way to store a vertex normal that will work for all of the facets it belongs to in the file, or, is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

A vertex is not just the position, a vertex is the whole tuple of its associated attributes. The normal is a vertex attribute. If vertices differ in any of their attributes, they're different vertices.

While it's perfectly possible to decompose the vertex attributes into multiple sets and use an intermediate indexing structure, this kind of data format is hard or even impossible to process for GPUs and also very cumbersome to work with. OpenGL for example can not directly use it.

Deduplication of certain vertex attributes (like the normal or other properties shared across vertices) makes sense only for storing the data. When you want to work with it, you normally expand it.

The data structure you have right now is what you want. Don't try to "optimize" it. Also even at 5 million vertices, given two attributes (position and normal) that's at most 100MiB of data. Modern computers have Gigabytes of RAM, so that's not really a problem.

Comment: currently the problem is rendering speed, which is really slow when using all verticies.  It is much faster when indexing the same vertex for the VBO than creating another, just a problem of normals now.  For size, I assume your talking about raw data, but just as a note, the stl file (ascii) is 500mb for the 5 million verticies.

I may be missing some understanding of opengl use of normals, but your saying this image http://www.uniqsoft.co.uk/directx/html/tut5/fig6.jpg would mean each vertex would have to store the green, not just the red

Comment: @user1938107: Deduplicating decomposed vertex attributes will actually kill any performance left, because it means to follow an indirection (indirections are expensive). And regarding the picture: Well, you normally will only store the average normals, at which point you can of course merge the vertices (gives you smooth shading as a bonus). If there's a hard edge between two facets you'll have to decompose those faces of course.

Comment: @user1938107: Most likely the way you supply your vertex data to OpenGL is probably suboptimal. You didn't show code, but 5M vertices are actually easy stuff for a GPU to digest. You just have to do it in the "right" way.

Comment: If I understand you, averaging normals and then merging verticies is possible (but will create smooth shading, not desirable on flat geometry).  From the beggining of your comment for indirection, would merging in this situation be more expensive (assuming the VBO method is not suboptimal)?

Comment: @user1938107: The problem is, that merging (deduplicating) vertex attributes makes it *really* hard to specify the vertex attribute layouts for OpenGL to process it. You'd need some kind of auxiliary data structure containing the indices into each attribute arrays'. You can no longer pass the attribute arrays as normal vertex attributes (because they're accessed by the same index). So a viable method would be to have a single vertex attribute and put the actual vertex data into textures. Then use texture access from the vertex shader. However this requires GPUs capable of VS texture access.

Comment: @user1938107: And this vertex shader texture access is detrimental to performance. You mentioned VBOs. Now's the question "how do you use them?". Seeing a bit of code would really help.

Answer (score 0):

The only straightforward approach in OpenGL is to create a vertex for each unique combination of position and normal. Depending on your data, this can still give you a very substantial reduction in the number of vertices. But if your data does not contain repeated vertices that share both position and normal, it will not help.

To validate if this will work for your data, you can extend the approach you already tried. Instead of using the 3 vertex coordinates as the key into your hash table, you use 6 values: the 3 vertex coordinates, and the 3 normal components.

If the number of entries in your hash table is significantly smaller than the original number of vertices, indexed rendering will be beneficial. You can then assign an index to each unique position/normal combination stored in the hash table, and used these indices to build the index buffer as well as the vertex buffer.

Beyond that, AMD defined an extension to support separate indices for different attributes, but this will not be useful if you want to keep your code portable: [GL_AMD_interleaved_elements](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/interleaved_elements.txt).